# Baggage locker in downtown San Francisco

Tags: luggage-storage, san-francisco

I'm staying at a hotel very close to the *San Francisco International Airport* on *S Airport Blvd, South San Francisco*.

I need to check out from the hotel Saturday morning and I have a flight back to Europe from the *Oakland International Airport*, same day in the evening.

I'm trying to maximize my time of visiting downtown San Francisco (the tourist stuff), therefore I'm thinking to take my luggage (something [like this](https://images3.campingworld.com/CampingWorld/images/products/8000/1000x1000/84588n-luggage.jpg)) downtown, after I check out from the hotel in the morning, leave it in some baggage locker, do my sightseeing, then around 16:00-17:00 take it and head to the *Oakland International Airport*.

Any reliable suggestions for a baggage locker downtown San Francisco? (please mention the price too, if known)

I found [this one](http://www.pier39.com/home/shop/services/california-welcome-center/) so far and they mention they do have baggage storage. Did anyone try it without problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there somewhere I can store luggage (one or two normal suitcases) in San Francisco for a few days?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67016/is-there-somewhere-i-can-store-luggage-one-or-two-normal-suitcases-in-san-fran)

Comment: @choster the suggestions given there are specific to the OP's circumstances and don't apply in this case.

Comment: Does the hotel near the airport also have a branch in the city? If so, it might be worth checking with the desk (email/phone in advance and ask) at your hotel if they could arrange to let you store your luggage at the bell desk at the other one - or see if they can suggest any alternate arrangements.

Comment: Good idea @BrendanMcK! Unfortunately the hotel didn't have another branch in the city, but idea could be useful for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Pier 39 California Welcome Center (as mentioned in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67016/is-there-somewhere-i-can-store-luggage-one-or-two-normal-suitcases-in-san-fran)) does offer luggage storage. It's [$5/bag](http://www.pier39.com/home/pier-info/frequently-asked-questions/#luggage), 7am-9pm. I've never used the service, but it's run by the state's tourism promotion organization and I would expect it to be reasonably reliable. The catch is the location: it's Pier 39, which is an extremely touristy area, and it's not directly connected to the main public transit (BART) train that you might use to get to the Oakland airport. As such, you will spend a chunk of your day in SF traveling to/from Pier 39 instead of seeing the city. If you plan to get to the airport by taxi (which could easily cost more than $60+tip depending on traffic), this is less of a problem.

A more central location to store your luggage would be the Union Square/Powell area, which is easily reachable by BART both from SFO and on your way to the Oakland airport. There are many hotels in this area, and while some will frown on storing luggage for non-guests, you may find an accommodating bellhop, especially if you're prepared to offer a tip. Saying you'll get a drink or bite to eat at the hotel restaurant could help. If they refuse, you could try another hotel. A few years ago, the Chancellor Hotel, just off Union Square, [was offering to store luggage](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60713-i30-k6387988-Where_can_luggage_be_left_for_the_day_in_San_Francisco-San_Francisco_California.html#48766550) for just a tip (thanks to [vacapinta on MetaFilter](https://ask.metafilter.com/239865/Where-to-store-luggage-near-the-Farmers-Market-in-San-Francisco#3478633) for this recommendation).

Another option might be the Temporary Transbay Terminal. The Amtrak office offers [luggage storage](https://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am/am2Station/Station_Page&code=SFC), though I'm not sure of the fee. This is a few blocks walk from the Embarcadero BART station and the Ferry Building.

Finally, you might try a museum coat check, particularly if your bags are on the smaller size and you plan to visit the museum anyway. SFMOMA (SF Museum of Modern Art) is near the Powell BART station and [their website](https://www.sfmoma.org/visit/visitor-guidelines/#section-coat-check) doesn't say anything about refusing luggage, just large instruments, animals, and bikes. It is, however, newly reopened after expansion and advance tickets are required to enter. The coat check downstairs might technically be accessible without a ticket though. The Asian Art Museum, near Civic Center BART, says they [take](http://www.asianart.org/visit/plan-your-visit) purses, bags, and large parcels. The Exploratorium (interactive science museum) has coin-operated lockers inside the ticketed area. Some in my experience are large enough to accommodate at least a carry-on sized bag.

Comment: Thank you, Zach! All suggestions are valid. I ended up using the 'Pier 39 California Welcome Center' without any problems. I chose this because it seemed the least time consuming option. I used a carpooling service to reach the airport, which was $46.

Answer (score 6):

The best storage downtown seems to be at the Chancellor Hotel on Union Square, 433 Powell St, San Francisco, CA 94102, +1 (415) 362-2004.  You don’t have to be a guest there to leave bags for a few hours.  They just ask that you tip the bellman when you drop the bags off and again when you pick them up.

Comment: I've just contacted them again (April 2018) and they still do this! Make sure to tip at drop-off and pick-up.